# swift filter 2d array by some value

Tags: arrays, swift, filter

I have an array like this

```
var cinema = Array(repeating: Array(repeating: 0, count: 30), count: 5)
```

user might input some values like this

```
cinema[1][20] = 5
cinema[1][21] = 6
```

Now, I would like to find out all nun 0 values and its index.
I think it is maybe possible to do it by for loop, but this is takes more time.
Is there a way to use something simpler? such as array.filter?

Comment: `filter` just "remove" the unwanted values, it won't give the index. A "for loop" doesn't necessary take more times, just more lines of code. But behind a `filter()` method for instance, a "for loop" internally wouldn't surprise me. Also, what would be the index for 5? 1, 20? Only 20?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```swift
cinema.map {
  $0.enumerated().filter { $0.element != 0 }
}
```

Comment: Yes. This is what I want, thank. I have based on this looked for something more, maybe would be interested for others.

Answer (score 0):

The code from @Jessy is correct.

```
cinema.map {
  $0.enumerated().filter { $0.element != 0 }
}
```

Additionally, one could try follows as well:

```
for (i, row) in cinema.enumerated() {
    for (j, cell) in row.enumerated().filter({$0.element != 0 }) {
      print("m[\(i),\(j)] = \(cell)")
  }
}
```